# Why does the type inference in C# not work with dynamic objects and generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I am working on a project that uses C# generics in combination with the dynamic keyword to implement a simple prototxt Caffe file parser, which is based on the proto2 syntax from the Google protocol buffer project.

The parser uses a very simple grammar to read in a prototxt file and store the values in a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

The dynamic objects are used to enable very flexible access to the values and to enable nesting of types, such as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>` during the parsing process and a generic method is used for type casting to enable autocompletion and reaasure type safety.

See the following scenario:

```
// prototxt file
layer {
  name: "conv2/norm2"
  …
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    …
  }
}

// method in C#
public T Try<T>(dynamic dict, string key, T @default = default(T)) {
  var result = @default;
  try {
    result = (T)dict[key];
  } catch {} // do nothing
  return result;
}
…

// usage
var learnParamDict = Try<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(layer, “lrn_param”);
```

**Now to my problem:**

When using the above code, the compiler does not really get that the return type of the method is typed to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` and shows dynamic only, but when pointing with the cursor to the Try method Visual Studio (the compiler) does describe the right types: [see image - part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGsG4.png)

I have experimented further and found out that you can completely ignore the Generic declaration and the static type definition, but this of course results to a Runtime Error: [see image - part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGsG4.png)

**Now to my questions:**

What is the correct behavior of the dynamic type inference, when working with generics? / Why is the type inference with dynamic objects and generics somehow unclear?

Shouldn't the compiler at least detect that I cannot use var with a generic method without declaring a type?

**Meta Info:**

I am using C# 6 with the Target framework setting for .NET Framework 4.6.2 and working with Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.1 (26403.7) Release.

Comment: Is `layer` typed as `dynamic` or as `object`?

Comment: `var learnParamDict = Try<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>((object)layer, "lrn_param");`

Comment: layer is also of type `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`

Comment: `dynamic` is not really a type, per se. It's is used to specifically instruct the compiler to ignore all of its compile-time type checks.  So it really shouldn't be all that surprising that the compiler doesn't check much at compile time; by using `dynamic` you've specifically instructed it not to.

Comment: But shouldn't the compiler check on the declared type T after it has been casted to T? What is the scope / influence range of dynamic. I thought in the scenario above after returning from the method, the compiler should check the types again.

Comment: @PetSerAI I have tried out your example and that also works. But I will try to find out within the C# specification, why the committed value disarms the type inference, although all states/types are clear for the compiler at that point.

Comment: I do believe this is correct behavior, it for one did not change across the last three VS releases and C# versions and a complete compiler rewrite.  Your basic question is "how much support does the Dynamic Language Runtime have for generic code".  With the unambiguous answer: "not as much as you hoped for" :)