# How to add a list of value and new keys to a nested dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

i'm again having a problem here,

I need to work with 2 dictionary with one nested like follow

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>> dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>>();
```

My problem is as follow, i need first add key to the parent dictionary that is an array, so i just do a foreach loop, that check this array. After that, if the key does not exist, we just add it to the parent dictionary, and we create a new dictionary on values like this :

```
foreach(var typeValue in Type)
{
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(typeValue))
    {
        dict.Add(typeValue, new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>();
    }
}
```

After that, i start to work on the innerDictionary, i also need to check if it contains specific key, and if not, create it and create a new List() as value on it.

```
dynamic mode = AnotherFunction()

foreach(var typeValue in Type)
{
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(typeValue))
    {
        dict.Add(typeValue, new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>();

        Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>> innerDict = dict[typeValue];

        if(!innerDict.ContainsKey(mode.id))
        {
             innerDict.Add(mode.id, new List<dynamic>());

        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to start here (according to the debug mode / errors that i will link at the end)

I then, need to add the dynamic variable to the list of the innerDict according to the move.id, and i then need to add the innerDict to the parent dict. So i do as follow

```
// Seems to work well
innerDict[move.id].Add(mode)

// Here, there is an error
dict[typeValue].Add(innerDict)
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't works, i mean, i add to the key that we iterate with the foreach, the innerDictionary that have the correct type.
I got the following error

```
"No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments"
```

Combined code :

```
dynamic mode = AnotherFunction()

foreach(var typeValue in Type)
{
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(typeValue))
    {
        dict.Add(typeValue, new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>();

        Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>> innerDict = dict[typeValue];

        if(!innerDict.ContainsKey(mode.id))
        {
             innerDict.Add(mode.id, new List<dynamic>());

        }
        // Seems to work well
        innerDict[move.id].Add(mode)

        // Here, there is an error
        dict[typeValue].Add(innerDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: is it related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006718/why-does-the-type-inference-in-c-sharp-not-work-with-dynamic-objects-and-generic dynamic tells the compiler the type can be changed in runtime

Comment: The problem is if List<dynamic> is null you need new List<dynamic>().

Comment: @BarışAkkurt Well, to tell you more, There is a JsonConvert that can deserialize between 9 different classes, and i "know" the class it need to deserialize to thanks to a parameter in the Json that i receive. But instead of doing 9 cases (that can be increased), i use dynamic type (i know it's not really justified in my case, and it's probably ugly) but i only need to access a "data" field in the json, they all have that "data" field, just there is not the same things in it, but i can get everything just by typing myDynamicObject.data for exemple, whatever the class is

Comment: @jdweng I already have a new List<dynamic> if the key mode.id does not exist, and since i create it without initializing any value to it, it does it before adding any values

Comment: You don't need the add.  Just set the value of the dict : dict[typeValue] = innerDict;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This instruction:

```
innerDict[move.id].Add(mode);
```

works because `innerDict` is a `Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>`, and this meand that `innerDict[move.id]` is a `List<dynamic>` which implements `Add` with a single argument.

This instruction:

```
dict[typeValue].Add(innerDict);
```

does not work because `dict` is a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>>`.
this means that `dict[typeValue]` is a `Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>` and the `Add` method it implements requires 2 arguments: a key and a value.

to make it work you can use:

```
dict[typeValue] = innerDict;
```

This was just to help you understand the error you get, but you should be aware that you don't need this instruction at all, since `innerDict` is already contained in `dict` (you added it with this line `dict.Add(typeValue, new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>();` and assigned it to innerDict with this one `Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>> innerDict = dict[typeValue];`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but i don't really understand the last part, i'm a bit confused here, i mean, by writing Dictionary<int, ...> innerDict = dict[TypeValue] , to me, it only say that innerDict take the value of what's inside dict[TypeValue] (so, either the new list that we created just above, or a list that already contains something), and after that, we say "Okay, now you can add to dict[typeValue] the list that was initialized from dict[typeValue]" by doing the last operation, dict[typeValue] = innerDict; PS : It works, but i don't really understand why, maybe my logic is wrong here

Comment: It's wrong to say that innerDict takes the value, it is a pointer that points to the memory area that contains the dictionary. dict[TypeValue] points to the same memory area, so when you add an element to the List pointed by dict[TypeValue] you are adding it to the same List pointed by innerDict