# C# Dynamic casting surpasses the type mismatch error for a different parameter

Tags: c#, generics, dynamictype

When I cast a variable to type `dynamic` before passing it to a generic type parameter of a function, the next parameter is bypassing the type check.

In the below snippet, how is the first call to `Check` method escaping the compilation?
The `(dynamic)` casting is done only to the first argument (where a `Type1` is passed to `Interface1`). But the second parameter where `Type1` is passed to `Interface2` is not failing in compilation.

```cs
interface Interface1 { }
interface Interface2 { }

class Type1 : Interface1 { }
class Type2 : Interface2 { }

class Program
{
    public static void Check<T1, T2>(T1 obj1, T2 obj2) where T1 : Interface1 where T2 : Interface2
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Check((dynamic)new Type1(), new Type1()); //passes compliation and fails in runtime

        Check(new Type1(), new Type1()); //fails in compilation
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006718/why-does-the-type-inference-in-c-sharp-not-work-with-dynamic-objects-and-generic#comment75044357_44006718?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dynamic` causes the generic type checking to be deferred until runtime. Once any any parameter is `dynamic` then the whole thing is deferred, so in the first statement the single `dynamic` causes the deferral.

Without it, in the second statement, the checking is done at compile-time and so fails as a compiler error.

In both cases the call is invalid: `obj2` cannot be of `Type1` because `Type1` does not implement `Interface2`. It's just a question of when the error is caught.

Answer (score 2):

When you use *any* dynamic values as an argument in a method invocation, the method is dynamically bound. If you're using generic type inference *at all* (whether or not the dynamic value is involved in that), generic type constraints aren't validated.

Here's a slightly simpler version of what you're seeing:

```cs
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic d = 1;
        // Compiles
        M(d, 0);

        // Doesn't compile - explicit type argument
        M<int>(d, 0);
    }

    static void M<T>(object ignored, T value) where T : class
    {
    }    
}
```

The compiler will do *some* checking, but it's relatively conservative in terms of what it checks. Fundamentally, if you're diving into the realm of dynamic binding, you should be *really* careful, and expect that things might not do as much type checking as you think it should.

(If I remember rightly, the spec is reasonably loose about exactly how much checking is performed for dynamically bound operations, so you could potentially get into a situation where it compiles with some compilers but not others.)